# validating checkbox limit javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, checkbox

```
var cbx = document.getElementById('ModelFilter').getElementsByTagName('input');
var ArrCB_l=cbx.length;

while(ArrCB_l--){
    var CB=ArrCB[ArrCB_l];
    CB.checked()==True;
    return 1
}
return 0
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?  I know the first line is the correct input as I am using it elsewhere for the same checkboxes, however this won't work?  I am trying to make sure there is at least one checkbox checked.  This function is called with an onsubmit event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(ArrCB_1) {
    if(cbx[--ArrCB_1].checked) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

.checked() should be just .checked

Answer (score 0):

```
while(ArrCB_l--){
    if (cbx[ArrCB_l].checked) {
       return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

your collection is `cbx` and not `ArrCB`, and checked is not a method but it's an attribute/property of the element

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('ModelFilter').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

this code returns all inputs(text,button,radio etc)

use

```
document.getElementById('ModelFilter').getElementsByTagName("input")[ArrCB_l].type == "checkbox"
```